# How to animate UIButton frame from left to right and reverse

Tags: ios, swift

My current method is to add a view to the button as subview:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 60))
button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
buttonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 60))
buttonView.backgroundColor = .black
button.addSubview(buttonView)
```

And then animate the width of the view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    }, completion: nil)
```

What I don't like about this is that the button title remains static. I want it to be part of the animation.

I also try to animate the frame of the button instead, but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens.
My button is added to the `UITextField` `inputAccessoryView` so I am not sure if this is the problem.

Any suggestions how can I animate the button correctly ?

Comment: You do not use AutoLayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an additional subview for UIButton in order to animate it's frame.

Try to add layoutIfNeeded() before animation and inside animation closure:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

view.addSubview(button)
button.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    button.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps.